# UIImageView not reflecting changed images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

In my project, I made an animation for my UIImageView using some pngs. I recently swapped those pngs out for different images (with different file names) and removed the previous pngs to the trash. I updated my code to reflect the file name change but when I build my application, I still see the animated images that are not referenced in my code anymore, and aren't even on my computer anymore. I tried cleaning the build and deleting/replacing the new images again, but nothing...

I am using XCode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had something like this happen. A few things you can check:

- Check you have added the new image files to your project.
- Delete the app from your device/simulator and re-build/re-run
- NSLog the filenames and check your are using the images you think you are.

Comment: Thanks a million Cannonade! I had tried checking the image files and NSLog'ing the filenames, but I didn't think about deleting the app from my simulator. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @derek Good stuff.  Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you should clean all the targets before new images gets reflected.